# Conditional headers using Joi

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, joi

I'm using Joi to validate the headers on a HTTP request. 
I have two headers. If FOO is present then BAR is required, otherwise BAR is optional. This works:

```
'FOO': Joi.string().optional(),
'BAR': Joi.string().when('FOO', { is: Joi.not(''), then: Joi.required() })
```

If I want FOO to be a numeric value then this works:

```
'FOO': Joi.number().integer().default(0).optional(),
'BAR': Joi.string().when('FOO', { is: Joi.number().min(1), then: Joi.required() })
```

However if I omit the default(0) then Joi thinks that BAR is required when FOO is not present. Is that correct behavior? Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

This can be made a lot simpler by using [`.with()`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#objectwithkey-peers). Consider the following schema:

```
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    FOO: Joi.number().default(0).min(1),
    BAR: Joi.string()
}).with('FOO', 'BAR');
```

The `.with()` forces `BAR` to be required only when `FOO` is present.

Also similar to your example it will also ensure `FOO` must be greater than or equal to `1` if it's actually in the payload, else Joi will default it to `0`.